# Create PDF automatically after new entry in database

Tags: database, t-sql, pdf

I am not sure if this is even the right site for this but I'll ask anyways.
Does anybody know a program that can create a PDF with data from a database with a complex SQL statement? When an employee finishes a request for a customer, I want that the program is triggered by the new entry in a database table and fills out a pre built PDF with data that it pulls from a database.
It needs to be a complex program that can process big SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS can produce PDF. See if that table insert trigger can call a CLR that in turn will execute the report that can even be attached to an email.

The report can be as complex as you need, so long the report SP can populate the data based on the newly inserted row.

For stability, let's not have a trigger, but the insert process itself should be done in an SP, in which that insertion SP shall call the CLR.

Further, instead of using CLR, we can use SSRS [Data-Driven Subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169673.aspx). When making the Subscription, we can make it as a **one time scheduled Job**. The SP can invoke this 'expired' Job from SQL Server Agent by using [sp_start_job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx).

Comment: I searched it on google but I don't think that's what I want. I want to be able to create a PDF which gets automatically filled out with data from a database with multiple where statements in many tables

Comment: Just added SSRS Data-Driven Subscription scheduled job that can be invoked by the SP.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do to run custom code in SQL Server is to create a CRL Stored Procedure and a trigger to start PDF processing in your specific use case. You can write a class library that connects to the database you are triggered from using a specific keyword in the connection string. You can pass in the key you need to use to select the whole dataset you need to fill the PDF as a SP parameter.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx

In the class library you can reference third part libraries to interact with an editable PDF and fill the flieds you need with the data retrieved from the database. I suggest you to have a look about security concerns releted to CLR use in SQL Server. Basically your code runs within the SQLServer.exe process, sharing resources and access privileges.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131071.aspx

Comment: I meant that I wanted a real PDF builder that does this. I think this isn't really helping me

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean with "real PDF builder"? Do you mean a library or what?

Comment: I need something that I can create a model for a PDF which later will get filled out automatically. Idk how to explain it in another way sorry